# Tool to automate android application which have no UI but runs in background

Tags: automation, android, background-application, testautomationfx

I am a new to android application testing.
I need to study the possibility of automating test cases for an android app which runs in background and will talk to a web service in a server. This app will periodically send particular information to the server DB.

I would like implement automation testing here to validate the major functionalities like the communication, events captured, performace data, capturing the crashes etc. Is there any tool which can help me out here?
I am seeing so many automation testing apps for applications with UI. But couldn't get one for apps which dont have any UI.

I am comfortable with vb scripting and perl. Also interested to dig new ways of automation. It would be a great help if someone can suggest some tools. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout for http://appium.io/ android automation tool uses JAVA as language. It would help you to automate.